# GoogleMaps, visualize Country based on a CountryCode

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a lists of *CountryCodes*, I would like to generate GoogleMap visualisations based on these CountryCodes. For example for China I have *"CN"* I would like to be able to generate an visualisation like this:

- https://goo.gl/maps/zyPk7

*Center* and *zoom* must to be automatic, due to the only information I have is the CountryCode

#### Update

I have tried with this code: [JSFiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/ff17mc4L/), I can *centre* and *zoom* based on CountryName but not based on CountryCode.

```
geocoder.geocode({"address": address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

When `address` is a CountryName it works, but I don't know how to make it works when `address` is a CountryCode.

Comment: What problems are you having doing that?

Comment: @geocodezip basically I want to know if it is possible. I see documentation centring maps based CountryName like [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?csw=1) but CountryCode is not working, also the _zoom_ is not automatically set to show the whole Country.

Comment: Sure it is possible.  You might need you own database of country codes to locations, or you might be able to find a FusionTable that has that data in it.  My favorite quote from [Marcelo's profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo): Motto2: Everything is possible, you just have to code it.

Comment: @geocodezip :).. obviously I was looking for an _out-of-the-box_ solution. GoogleMaps has a very powerful geocode library I was expecting it to support CountryCodes as well as CountryNames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding the 2 character ISO 3166 code plus the string "country" works for me:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function codeAddress(selectItem) {
  var address = document.getElementById('addr_sel')[selectItem.selectedIndex].value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    "address": address + " country"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

$("#geocode_button").on("click", codeAddress);

initialize();
```

```css
     #map-canvas {
       height: 400px;
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       border: 1px solid red;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW" />
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="addr_sel" onchange="codeAddress(this)">
  <!-- ISO 3166 codes from http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 -->
  <option value="AF">AF</option>
  <option value="AX">AX</option>
  <option value="AL">AL</option>
  <option value="DZ">DZ</option>
  <option value="AS">AS</option>
  <option value="AD">AD</option>
  <option value="AO">AO</option>
  <option value="AI">AI</option>
  <option value="AQ">AQ</option>
  <option value="AG">AG</option>
  <option value="AR">AR</option>
  <option value="AM">AM</option>
  <option value="AW">AW</option>
  <option value="AU">AU</option>
  <option value="AT">AT</option>
  <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
  <option value="BS">BS</option>
  <option value="BH">BH</option>
  <option value="BD">BD</option>
  <option value="BB">BB</option>
  <option value="BY">BY</option>
  <option value="BE">BE</option>
  <option value="BZ">BZ</option>
  <option value="BJ">BJ</option>
  <option value="BM">BM</option>
  <option value="BT">BT</option>
  <option value="BO">BO</option>
  <option value="BA">BA</option>
  <option value="BW">BW</option>
  <option value="BV">BV</option>
  <option value="BR">BR</option>
  <option value="IO">IO</option>
  <option value="BN">BN</option>
  <option value="BG">BG</option>
  <option value="BF">BF</option>
  <option value="BI">BI</option>
  <option value="KH">KH</option>
  <option value="CM">CM</option>
  <option value="CA">CA</option>
  <option value="CV">CV</option>
  <option value="KY">KY</option>
  <option value="CF">CF</option>
  <option value="TD">TD</option>
  <option value="CL">CL</option>
  <option value="CN">CN</option>
  <option value="CX">CX</option>
  <option value="CC">CC</option>
  <option value="CO">CO</option>
  <option value="KM">KM</option>
  <option value="CG">CG</option>
  <option value="CD">CD</option>
  <option value="CK">CK</option>
  <option value="CR">CR</option>
  <option value="CI">CI</option>
  <option value="HR">HR</option>
  <option value="CU">CU</option>
  <option value="CY">CY</option>
  <option value="CZ">CZ</option>
  <option value="DK">DK</option>
  <option value="DJ">DJ</option>
  <option value="DM">DM</option>
  <option value="DO">DO</option>
  <option value="EC">EC</option>
  <option value="EG">EG</option>
  <option value="SV">SV</option>
  <option value="GQ">GQ</option>
  <option value="ER">ER</option>
  <option value="EE">EE</option>
  <option value="ET">ET</option>
  <option value="FK">FK</option>
  <option value="FO">FO</option>
  <option value="FJ">FJ</option>
  <option value="FI">FI</option>
  <option value="FR">FR</option>
  <option value="GF">GF</option>
  <option value="PF">PF</option>
  <option value="TF">TF</option>
  <option value="GA">GA</option>
  <option value="GM">GM</option>
  <option value="GE">GE</option>
  <option value="DE">DE</option>
  <option value="GH">GH</option>
  <option value="GI">GI</option>
  <option value="GR">GR</option>
  <option value="GL">GL</option>
  <option value="GD">GD</option>
  <option value="GP">GP</option>
  <option value="GU">GU</option>
  <option value="GT">GT</option>
  <option value="GG">GG</option>
  <option value="GN">GN</option>
  <option value="GW">GW</option>
  <option value="GY">GY</option>
  <option value="HT">HT</option>
  <option value="HM">HM</option>
  <option value="VA">VA</option>
  <option value="HN">HN</option>
  <option value="HK">HK</option>
  <option value="HU">HU</option>
  <option value="IS">IS</option>
  <option value="IN">IN</option>
  <option value="ID">ID</option>
  <option value="IR">IR</option>
  <option value="IQ">IQ</option>
  <option value="IE">IE</option>
  <option value="IM">IM</option>
  <option value="IL">IL</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
  <option value="JM">JM</option>
  <option value="JP">JP</option>
  <option value="JE">JE</option>
  <option value="JO">JO</option>
  <option value="KZ">KZ</option>
  <option value="KE">KE</option>
  <option value="KI">KI</option>
  <option value="KP">KP</option>
  <option value="KR">KR</option>
  <option value="KW">KW</option>
  <option value="KG">KG</option>
  <option value="LA">LA</option>
  <option value="LV">LV</option>
  <option value="LB">LB</option>
  <option value="LS">LS</option>
  <option value="LR">LR</option>
  <option value="LY">LY</option>
  <option value="LI">LI</option>
  <option value="LT">LT</option>
  <option value="LU">LU</option>
  <option value="MO">MO</option>
  <option value="MK">MK</option>
  <option value="MG">MG</option>
  <option value="MW">MW</option>
  <option value="MY">MY</option>
  <option value="MV">MV</option>
  <option value="ML">ML</option>
  <option value="MT">MT</option>
  <option value="MH">MH</option>
  <option value="MQ">MQ</option>
  <option value="MR">MR</option>
  <option value="MU">MU</option>
  <option value="YT">YT</option>
  <option value="MX">MX</option>
  <option value="FM">FM</option>
  <option value="MD">MD</option>
  <option value="MC">MC</option>
  <option value="MN">MN</option>
  <option value="ME">ME</option>
  <option value="MS">MS</option>
  <option value="MA">MA</option>
  <option value="MZ">MZ</option>
  <option value="MM">MM</option>
  <option value="NA">NA</option>
  <option value="NR">NR</option>
  <option value="NP">NP</option>
  <option value="NL">NL</option>
  <option value="AN">AN</option>
  <option value="NC">NC</option>
  <option value="NZ">NZ</option>
  <option value="NI">NI</option>
  <option value="NE">NE</option>
  <option value="NG">NG</option>
  <option value="NU">NU</option>
  <option value="NF">NF</option>
  <option value="MP">MP</option>
  <option value="NO">NO</option>
  <option value="OM">OM</option>
  <option value="PK">PK</option>
  <option value="PW">PW</option>
  <option value="PS">PS</option>
  <option value="PA">PA</option>
  <option value="PG">PG</option>
  <option value="PY">PY</option>
  <option value="PE">PE</option>
  <option value="PH">PH</option>
  <option value="PN">PN</option>
  <option value="PL">PL</option>
  <option value="PT">PT</option>
  <option value="PR">PR</option>
  <option value="QA">QA</option>
  <option value="RE">RE</option>
  <option value="RO">RO</option>
  <option value="RU">RU</option>
  <option value="RW">RW</option>
  <option value="SH">SH</option>
  <option value="KN">KN</option>
  <option value="LC">LC</option>
  <option value="PM">PM</option>
  <option value="VC">VC</option>
  <option value="WS">WS</option>
  <option value="SM">SM</option>
  <option value="ST">ST</option>
  <option value="SA">SA</option>
  <option value="SN">SN</option>
  <option value="RS">RS</option>
  <option value="SC">SC</option>
  <option value="SL">SL</option>
  <option value="SG">SG</option>
  <option value="SK">SK</option>
  <option value="SI">SI</option>
  <option value="SB">SB</option>
  <option value="SO">SO</option>
  <option value="ZA">ZA</option>
  <option value="GS">GS</option>
  <option value="ES">ES</option>
  <option value="LK">LK</option>
  <option value="SD">SD</option>
  <option value="SR">SR</option>
  <option value="SJ">SJ</option>
  <option value="SZ">SZ</option>
  <option value="SE">SE</option>
  <option value="CH">CH</option>
  <option value="SY">SY</option>
  <option value="TW">TW</option>
  <option value="TJ">TJ</option>
  <option value="TZ">TZ</option>
  <option value="TH">TH</option>
  <option value="TL">TL</option>
  <option value="TG">TG</option>
  <option value="TK">TK</option>
  <option value="TO">TO</option>
  <option value="TT">TT</option>
  <option value="TN">TN</option>
  <option value="TR">TR</option>
  <option value="TM">TM</option>
  <option value="TC">TC</option>
  <option value="TV">TV</option>
  <option value="UG">UG</option>
  <option value="UA">UA</option>
  <option value="AE">AE</option>
  <option value="GB">GB</option>
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="UM">UM</option>
  <option value="UY">UY</option>
  <option value="UZ">UZ</option>
  <option value="VU">VU</option>
  <option value="VE">VE</option>
  <option value="VN">VN</option>
  <option value="VG">VG</option>
  <option value="VI">VI</option>
  <option value="WF">WF</option>
  <option value="EH">EH</option>
  <option value="YE">YE</option>
  <option value="ZM">ZM</option>
  <option value="ZW">ZW</option>
</select>
```